# Parallel Programming with Tools

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore, parallel-processing

I was looking into Intel's Parallel Studio. It said it is for C & C++ programmers. I know C# 4.0 has a lot of parallelism features. I like a few things in Parallel Studio. Can Parallel Studio be used for C# as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an article](http://softtalkblog.com/2009/09/24/parallel-studio-to-support-c-in-2010-but-not-java/) that claims Parallel Studio will have C# support this year.